# how to insure a certain field in a class has different and unique values in all instances in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to coding and I've faced this problem recently: I'm working on a class which has various fields, and I want to insure  each instance of the class has a unique value for a certain field using static variables. for example, consider this class:

```
public class NetworkNode  {
private String NodeName;
private int NodeNumber;
private boolean NodeAttraction;
....
}
```

in the code above, I want to insure each object created from the class NetworkNode to have a unique and different NodeNumber or in other words, no two NetworkNode objects should have the same NodeNumber field.
what are the ways to do this? thanks.

Comment: Have a list of `WeakReference`s to all instances.

Comment: Make your constructor protected and have a public static factory method to keep track of the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could automatically assign a different `NodeNumber` to each instance if you don't care about the actual value as long as it's unique. Using static variables you could create a private static counter `nextNodeNumber` in your class `NetworkNode`:

```
private static int nextNodeNumber = 0;
```

In your constructor you could then do

```
public NetworkNode() {
    this.NodeNumber = nextNodeNumber;
    ++nextNodeNumber;
    ...
}
```

This way you just have to ensure, that there is no other way to set/change `NodeNumber` or `nextNodeNumber`.

If you are using multiple Threads you would have to secure access to `nextNodeNumber` to prevent asynchronous access.

Answer (score 0):

1 put a

`static Set<String> myuniquevalues ...` (for example) for each of your fields

2 in your constructor

```
public NetworkNode  (String value1 ...) 
{... check if value1  exists in myuniquevalues , and throw exceptions }
```

3 if your objects are deleted, you must manage it also ...

**Alternative**: concentrate creation of your objects in a factory, and manage unicity there.

Comment: since he is using an `int` for `nodenumber` might be better to increment it and check again instead of throwing an exception

Comment: @hellyale . as the nodenumber is passed and fixed (and expected ?, we dont know), I wouldnt change it. Usually, if the constructor fails, one throws exception, but it's a choice of design.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do some reading about variables and what static means. To make it short, a static variable exists only "once" in your program.

For example, if you create a game, you want the variable score to be static since there will only be one instance of this variable.

In order to have each NetworkNode to have a unique and different NodeNumber, you have to construct the object like this:

```
public NetworkNode(String NodeName, int NodeNumber, boolean NodeAttraction){

  this.NodeName = NodeName; 
  this.NodeNumber = NodeNumber; 
  this.NodeAttraction = NodeAttraction; 

}
```

See, here, each NetworkNode will have a different value for each of the variables passed as parameters.

You will then just need to create the object in your main function or whatever like this for example:

```
NetworkNode myNode = new NetworkNode("node1", 0, true);
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks. the problem is the value of NodeNumber integers are supposed to be read from a file. I want to keep track of all NodeNumbers of all objects and if the constructor gives a certain NetworkNode's NodeNumber a repetitive value which was used before, the constructor shouldn't make any new object there and possibly throw an exception.